# dj-rest-auth, django-allauth, mongodb authentication

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, djongo, dj-rest-auth

i want to integrate user authentication in my django projet,
i'm using dj-rest-auth, django-allauth and my db is mongodb
but when i execute `python manage.py migrate` i get this error:

```
File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 830, in __iter__
   raise exe from e
djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError: 

   Keyword: FAILED SQL: SELECT %(0)s AS "a" FROM "django_site" LIMIT 1
Params: (1,)
Version: 1.3.6
   Sub SQL: None
   FAILED SQL: None
   Params: None
   Version: None
```

so how can i fix this issue ? please